# Migrating Angular 8 to angular 13

Tags: angular, angular8, angular13

I am planning to migrate an application which is based on angular 8  to angular 13, its a medium size application which contain 30-40 modules, how many months will take to complete this job with 1 developer?,  the application is not contains any complex modules

Answer (score 1):

We have recently migrated from angular 9 to angular 13 and we have around 10 to 15 modules and it took around 7 - 8 man-days excluding testcases. As test cases took a bit more to fix and work on.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get help from https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.0-13.0 to upgrade faster. if it does not have any complex modules then it should not take long. only resolving version conflicts may take a little time.